# Deploy Symfony applications across multiple servers

Tags: symfony1

For my Symfony application, I have at least two modules:

1. Login Module
2. Processing Module

The Login Module is located on the gateway server; it does all the authentication when a user is first logging in. After that, it redirects to the processing module which is located on another server. Note that there can be many servers handling processing module.

The issue is how to keep the session persistence across different servers in Symfony? I plan to store my session data in a database. Is it that

1. Making the database public to all the servers
2. [Pointing the user session management database to that database](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer)

Will do? Is there anything I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I found on how to deploy Symfony applications [across multiple servers](http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-deploy-symfony-application.html).

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you correctly: you have 1 symfony app with two modules that should be on min 2 different servers ( logon on  one server, process on 2 or more servers).

wouldn't be better to separate those modules to different apps ( coz of their deployment on different servers)

for example: app with login on 1st server and after login it redirects to a on of the servers that has app with processing module.

for this to work you need to store session data to database ( there are existing adapters for mysql and pdo).

and that sould suffice.

Comment: Yes, you are right; and I got this figure out, thanks for your answer.